# Where should I unregister a broadcast receiver when your class extends Application and not Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I know that when my class extends `Activity`, I can register a receiver in `onCreate()` or `onStart()` and de-register on `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`.

But what if my class extends `Application` - where will I de-register my receiver?

Normally `onTerminate()` overridden method will never be called for a real device.

Comment: Your application logic should decide when to register and unregister. You should register when you are interested in getting the event callbacks, and unregister when you are no longer interested.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't register broadcast receiver in your Application class. For that purposes you have to declare it via AndroidManifest

Comment: There are events that, cannot be registered in the AndroidManifest, for instance `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` (see https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/).

Comment: @Trinimon Don't understand your thought. For what to register it in Application class?

Comment: My comment was related to _"For that purposes you have to declare it via AndroidManifest"_. This is not always valid, because it might be that you _have to_ register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the code. I see it rather like David: register the receiver on start up of the component that is interested in the event and unregister it, once the component is destroyed.

Comment: @Trinimon  I think author trying to register BR in Application, because he wants to have BR alive during all time of life of application, or even more. Btw, he knows about how to register/unregister BR in Activities.

Comment: Based on the fact that the OP registers the event programmatically I took into consideration that a registration in the manifest might not be an option (thus my comment). In such a case OP could (for instance) start a stick service and register the `BroadcastReceiver` on start. This way he could have a BroadcastReceiver that is alive during the app life time.

Comment: It is not written in the documentation that you shouldn't register it in the app class https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#context-registered_receivers

Comment: Not all obvious things should be in documentation.